# Tricking programs in C

Tags: c, portable-applications

Say I launch a program from the program I make.  Is it possible to trick the launched program into thinking the windows directory is in a different place?

Comment: "Windows Directroy" and "Portable application"? That's just wrong. And it has nothing to do with C. Care to retag and retitle?

Comment: I am going to be programming it in C and I am doing it with the goal of making an app portable.

Comment: What you describe is pretty much the _opposite_ of "portable", as the term is generally used by software developers: code that can be compiled and executed on a wide variety of operating systems or processor architectures without having to modify it.  Once you assume there's such a thing as "the windows directory", you've restricted yourself to running on Windows.

Comment: I realize I am not using the traditional meaning of the programming definition of "portable."  However, I looked in the portable-applications section and they were discussing portable in the since that I could take an app from one system and transfer it to another like system without having it dependent on files in the win dir of the new system.

Comment: Now your request makes even less sense than before!  If you want to launch a program that's capable of finding the windows directory for itself, why would you need to "trick" it to get it to run on a machine with a different Windows directory?

Comment: From what you've said you're almost certainly trying to use the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Okay, I am just going to reask my question later with much more detail, par Alan's suggestion.  Feel free to tear it apart then, too.

Comment: Try just adding the fake directory to the 'PATH' and see whether that works: because the app may be looking on its 'PATH' for files, not looking explicitly in the Windows directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult. There are several system APIs which the program might be using to determine the path of the windows directory. To trick it you would need to intercept the program's calls to whichever API it is, and return a different result.

There are many articles about intercepting APIs on Windows: here's the first one I found using Google: [API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If it uses the `%windir%` or `%systemroot%` environment variables to determine the Windows directory, it would certainly be easy to change these.  But if it uses an API call, you'll have to hook that call, as [ChrisW suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352046/tricking-programs-in-c/1352059#1352059).  You might take a look at [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Answer (score 2):

Faking the location of the windows directory is generally not something that is done.  My own reaction is similar to those above, that its a recipe for disaster if it were even possible.

If you could explain your situation in more detail (possibly in a new question), there might be better suggestions to solve your actual underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

The location of Windows directory is in the Registry. Vista may let you change it per user, but as far as I know it's impossible to do per-process.